# How to get back the declined READ permission with Facebook Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook

We have one Android app which needs 2 extra read permission-

1. Email
2. User_Friends

If user accepts both the permission then everything is fine. However, if user declines either one of them while logging first time and later when we need this information then we are trying to ask back this permission using code:-

```
final String[] PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ = { "email", "user_friends" };
                    final List<String> permissionList = Arrays.asList(PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ);




                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        mActivity, permissionList).setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
                        .setRequestCode(REAUTH_FRIEND_PERMISSION_CODE);


                session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

On executing the above code, if Facebook app is present then it does not show any Facebook dialog but just a black screen for few milliseconds and come back with the old decline permission again as declined. And also the **resultCode** value is **-1** in **onActivityResult** method.

I was reading here the example of reauthentication but could not find anything suitable for Android.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication

It will be useful for me if anybody can share the experience.

PS: I am using latest Facebook SDK 3.16.0